# Can't find workflow deployed as WSP solution

Tags: deployment, solution-package, solution-deployment

I am new to SharePoint, sorry if answer to my question is obvious.

I am trying to deploy my very simple workflow as WSP package, it deploys without errors, I activate it, but I can't find my workflow and associate it with list. Could you help me, please, what I do wrong?

I do it so:

[here is version with screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680544/cant-find-workflow-deployed-as-wsp-solution-when-i-deploy-it-from-vs-it-works) (I can't add screenshots here because of lack of reputation).

1. Create an empty SharePoint project in VS, choose trust level as a Farm solution
2. Add simple State Machine Workflow (list workflow, not site), associate it with the Task lisk.
3. Press CTRL-F5 in VS2010, and see that WF appears, retract it.
4. Pack it to WSP package, upload and activate it.
5. Check is it associated to list. It doesn't. (As far as I know it is normal)
6. Try to associate it manually, but I can't see it (List tools/list/workflow settings/add workflow). Why? Where is my error?

I think that I missed something important in basic priciples, but I can't understand what. Help me please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: in which way are you uploading it to your SP? are you using the web-interface? central-administration? shell?

Comment: web-interface (site actions\site settings\galleries\solutions)

Comment: Looks like you found the issue, as displayed on your stackoverflow post. Please post answer to this site as well.

Comment: Yes, I've found it. Ok, thank you for reminding. Now I can post it (I have to wait at least 8 hours to post the answer because of lack of my reputation). Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. The root of the problem is next:
I've tryed to add WSP Farm solution to sandbox solution gallery. I have to use another way for deploying, for example PowerShell.

PS: Thanks to [Balamurugan-S KAUST answer](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/f73236e8-98e7-4a4d-a9cb-c543ab59aca9)